# Angular 8: Mark Form as Touched from Parent Component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8, angular-reactive-forms

How do I declare a Child Component Form Mark Touched from a Parent component?

Currently in the child component, we have an input variable and ngOnChanges which works

```
@Input public markFormTouchedFlag: boolean

if (this.markFormTouchedFlag) { 
    this.addressform.markAllAsTouched();
}
```

Curious, if there is a more efficient way to make a child component form (addressform) as touched from a Parent Component?

Maybe should make question more generic, find formvalidity, markuntouched, but I will stick with first question only.

Comment: so above method is working or not when you are passing markFormTouchedFlag = true from parent

Comment: I hope above is working, also if you want to make it dynamic, just create variable of observable type and send the updated value which you have to listen in the child component and make it Touched as required.

Comment: yes, method above is working, wondering if there is more efficient way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in a more improvised way if you need to pass the same variable("markFormTouchedFlag") to multiple components you can use this method. This method storing data in the observable and by subscribing to this will update variable auto where ever it is used.

create service to store data:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class FlagService {
    private subject = new Subject<any>();

    updateFlag(flag: bool) {
        this.subject.next({ flag: flag });
    }

    setFlag() {
        this.subject.next();
    }

    getFlag(): Observable<any> {
        return this.subject.asObservable();
    }
}
```

create parent component:

```
import { Component, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

import { FlagService } from '../services/FlagService.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})

export class AppComponent implements OnDestroy {
    flag: any;
    subscription: Subscription;

    constructor(private flagService: FlagService) {}

    setFlag(): void {
     this.flagService.setFlag(flag);
   }

   clearFlag(): void {
       this.messageService.clearMessage();
   }
}
```

In this component (parent component) we are having two functions set and clear flag. **Setflag** function is used to set the value in service. once it is set in the service layer where ever value is subscribed it will be updated. **clearFlag** function is used to set the variable with a null value.

child component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { FlagService } from '../services/FlagService.service';

@Component({ templateUrl: 'home.component.html' })
export class HomeComponent {
    
 flag: any;
 subscription: Subscription;

 constructor(private flagService: FlagService) {
     this.subscription = this.flagService.getFlag().subscribe(flag => { this.flag = flag; });
 }

 ngOnDestroy() {
     this.subscription.unsubscribe();
 }
```

By this, you are able to get the value from observable, whenever the flag is changed in service, it will be automatically updated in the child component once it is changed in parent component and it is set to flag in the component because of the subscription made in the constructor.

on component destroy we are unsubscribing for value.

Comment: seems like we are strongly tying with services, also lot of code for form touched, I will review it though, thanks